# Position in a string C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to know how I check the character in first position in a string on C# code. For example , if the first character is the character "&" or other.

Thanks.

Comment: You might consider finding a good introductory book about C#. Or some online tutorial material. That'll be a whole lot easier and much faster than asking basic questions and waiting for a reply.

Comment: You are right, Im new in C# and Im just trying to learn myself, and I thought who knows more than me not bother to help the inexperienced, my mistake, sorry everybody!

Comment: I didn't intend my comment as criticism, but rather encouragement to find a beginner's tutorial and, you know, *learn*. You got plenty of answers to your question in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the answers, there are many ways to accomplish this. You should be careful to avoid exceptions that will be thrown if you attempt to call methods on a `string` that is `null` or use indexers on a `string` that is `null` or empty.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input[0] == '&')
{
    // yes
}
```

or…

```
if(input != null && input.StartsWith("&"))
{
    // yes
}
```

Comment: "An answer that doesn't check for null is null and void," as they say...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way without needing multiple checks is to use the [String.CompareOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es986b3k.aspx) overload.

```
string test = "&string";
if (String.CompareOrdinal(test, 0, "&", 0, 1) == 0) {
  // String test started with &
}
```

This has the added benefit of not needing to check for null or empty as the static method handles those automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = "&myString";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) && test[0] == '&')
{
    // first character is &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) method.

```
if (MyString.StartsWith("&")) {
    // do something.
}
```